# C# Entity Framework: Is this code optimal? How can I improve it?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, coding-style, transactions

I feel like the following code is suboptimal, and that it *could* be better. I just don't know how to fetch the key without commiting the changes.

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var update = new DAL.ServerStatus
{
    Accounts = status.Accounts,
    Clients = status.Clients,
    Created = now,
    ServerStarted = status.ServerStarted,
    ServerDateTime = status.ServerDateTime
};

var context = DataContext.GetDataContext();
context.ServerStatus.AddObject(update);
context.SaveChanges();

foreach (var character in characters)
{
    var characterUpdate = new DAL.ServerOnlineCharacter
    {
        Account = character.Account,
        Alliance = character.Alliance,
        Created = now,
        Criminal = character.Criminal,
        DonationPoints = character.DonationPoints,
        EventCredits = character.EventCredits,
        FactionTyped = character.FactionTyped,
        FactionPoints = character.FactionPoints,
        Fame = character.Fame,
        GameTime = character.GameTime,
        Guild = character.Guild,
        GuildAbbreviation = character.GuildAbbreviation,
        GuildTitle = character.GuildTitle,
        Karma = character.Karma,
        Kills = character.Kills,
        MapTyped = character.MapTyped,
        RaceTyped = character.RaceTyped,
        RawName = character.RawName,
        Serial = character.Serial,
        ServerStatusId = update.Id
    };

    context.ServerOnlineCharacters.AddObject(characterUpdate);
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Ideally I'd want this to be transactional, and not having to go twice to the database to fully commit the changes. How could I achieve this?

This is the method stub by the way:

```
static void Update(IServerStatusUpdate status, IEnumerable<IServerOnlineCharacterUpdate> characters);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have update.Id mapped as a primary key, and there's a relationship mapped between ServerOnlineCharacter and ServerStatus, then you should be able to do

```
characterUpdate.ServerStatus = update
```

instead of

```
characterUpdate.ServerStatusId = update.Id
```

This would allow you to only need to call context.SaveChanges at the end (and not in the middle).

As far as making the method transactional, EntityFramework abides by TransactionScope, so if you wrap your Update around a TransactionScope and commit it when you're ready, it should execute as you'd expect.

[Here's an example of transaction usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738523.aspx#Y206)

And if you really want to go the extra mile, you might want to take a look at something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map your interface you're passing into Update to your DAL class. That would reduce a lot of code there.

Comment: If I invoke `SaveChanges` just once, will the operation still be non-transactional?

Comment: SaveChanges will be atomic - either all the changes succeed or SaveChanges will roll back its transaction and throw an exception.